# Sharing data between multiple macOS installs

Tags: macos, sharing

For development purposes I need to have multiple versions of macOS installed.

Here is the setup I have at the moment:

- 1Tb drive is split into 3 partitions
- 300Gb goes to System 1
- 300Gb goes to System 2
- 400Gb are left as a shared volume

Shared volume will have Applications folder for apps that can be installed in non-system folders and can be shared between systems (like IntelliJ IDEA)

And, of course, lots of projects backed by Git.

Problem is so far is that while System 1 is running it can create some files with default permissions belonging to Username in System 1 and without writeable permissions to Others. Same goes for System 2.

Because I have to switch back and forth multiple times a day, you can see how this setup isn't very convenient.

Any other options? A script that can somehow be started every time system is about to reboot to chmod everything recursively? A shared user maybe, or a shared permission system somehow?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your requirement / intent to maintain different major versions of macOS or just several installs of the same version that gets upgraded mostly at the same time?

Comment: There are various options but one that comes to mind is to clone the older os two the 2nd drive, then upgrade so that both basically have the same users.

Comment: One of the os-es has to stay because it's a special work-related setup, another one is a regular os install. So I can't clone one into the other, basically